# Can I use this fast charger for my Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, power, power-supply

It is a fast charger and says 5V/10W and also says 45.0W MAX? Please help me out.

I don't know what to do. Will it destroy my Pi 4?

[image: photograph of label]

Comment: what is your exact concern? ... are you concerned about the quality of the power supply?

Comment: I wouldn't use that phone charger, it says the output can be 10V on the base. 10V will fry a Raspberry Pi good and toasty with a frosting of blue smoke.

Comment: I think the over voltage protection will take care of that, otherwise it would be pointless to have a over voltage protection circuit there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the model number on the label (WC065A21GB) this seems to be a 65W [OnePlus Warp Charge Power Adapter](https://www.oneplus.com/us/product/oneplus-warp-charge-65-power-adapter), intended to fast charge certain models of OnePlus smartphones.

I can't find much details (e.g. a datasheet) of this product, so it's hard to say how it exactly works and what voltage it will output in your case.
Since this charger is not designed to be used as a generic power supply, but mainly as a dedicated charger for one specific ranger of products, ***I don't expect a datasheet of it exists, or that you can rely on certain specifications when using it with other products than the ones it's intended for.***

Note that the website says:

> The power output depends on the device the charger is connected to.

It also mentions this about compatibility:

> - Warp Charge 65: OnePlus 8T / 9 / 9 Pro / Nord 2 5G
> - Warp Charge 30: OnePlus 7 Pro / 7T / 7T Pro / Nord / N10 / Nord CE 5G
> - Fast Charge: OnePlus 3 / 3T / 5 / 5T / 6 / 6T / 7 / N100

I *think* this means that the first group of devices can be charged with 65 W (6.5 A at 10 V), the second group can be charged at 30 W (using another voltage higher than 5 V), and the third group can charge "fast" (probably limited to 15 W, i.e. 5 V / 3 A).

However, practically speaking, ***it seems to be a USB-C power adapter supporting the USB Power Delivery 3.0 protocol***.

The reason I think this is the following:

- USB Power Delivery 1.0 uses 5 V, 12 V, and 20 V.
- USB Power Delivery 2.0/3.0 add 9 V and 15 V to this list.
- USB Power Delivery 3.1 even adds higher voltages, up to 48 V!
- The voltages listed on your power supply correspond to the ones used in Power Deliver protocols 1.0 to 3.0 (5, 9, 12, 15, and 20 V).
- The label also mentions the terms **PDO** and **PPS**, which are terms from the USB Power Delivery 3.0 protocol (Power Data Objects and Programmable Power Supply, respectively).

If both the charger and the USB device (in your case the Raspberry Pi 4) are conforming to the USB standard, they should "negotiate" the power delivery. In other words, the charger should only increase the voltage if the device has let it know that it can handle it. The USB Power Delivery protocol specifies how that is done, but that is something the end-user shouldn't know about. It should be safe to use.

***However***, it is possible that the manufacturer has used some "tricks" to recognize a certain device and enable the 10 V charging mode. If that's the case, it can definitely damage<sup>1</sup> your Raspberry Pi. I think there's only one way to find out, and it's up to you if you're willing to take that risk.

Also note that your warranty is void if doing this, since neither of the manufacturers claim that these products are compatible, and in fact Raspberry Pi recommends to use the official power supply.

A final note: also make sure to use proper USB cables. The original USB standard was limited to 500 mA, so certain cables might not be designed for the high currents that modern-day USB devices consume (roughly 3 A in case of the Raspberry Pi 4).

---

<sup>1</sup> The ***absolute maximum rating*** for the Raspberry Pi 4 is 6.0 V (see [datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-datasheet.pdf)), meaning that it may get damaged if such a voltage is applied even for a short time.