# Can I use this power supply?

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

The maximum power supply for a Raspberry Pi 4 is 5V/3A but here I have a 5V/3.1A power supply. Can I use this power supply? Will I fry my Pi 4?

Below is a photograph of the power supply. The text on the label is:

```
PNG XE
Model: AD-118
Input: 110-240V
Output: 5V-3.1A
```

[image: photograph of power supply - PNG XE Model AD-118]

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for anyone here to say definitively whether or not the "power supply" in your picture will *"fry your pi"*. This is because - we don't have/you simply have not provided - enough information on it. There are many electrical specifications for a power supply in addition to its voltage output, and its current capacity.

That said, the 5V, 3.1A spec printed on the supply ***suggests*** it ***might*** be OK for powering your RPi. This is ***your choice***: if you use this supply, you'll have to take some risk that it might damage your RPi - or cause it to malfunction. If you're not willing to take that risk, then you should buy a supply that is designed to support the RPi.

Comment: This answer is just rambling and falls into the category "conspiracy theory"!

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why this power supply would "fry" your Raspberry Pi 4.

The [Raspberry Pi website](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) says you'll need a 15 W power supply. The power supply in the picture meets that requirement.

The fact that the power supply can deliver 3.1 A and the Raspberry Pi only needs 3 A doesn't mean it will fry it.

Having said that, of course it's possible that this is very bad quality power supply which might affect the performance of your Raspberry Pi. That's probably why the official Raspberry Pi USB-C Power Supply is recommended. But generally speaking, based on these specs I personally wouldn't worry about it.

---

**NOTE:** Another concern is ***personal safety***. Usually any electrical component (in this case power adapter) is either grounded or doubly isolated. As far as I know, in many countries this is mandatory: if an adapter is not grounded, it **must** be doubly isolated. Your power adapter is not.

You can easily see if a product is grounded or not by checking if there's a third (metal) conductor. In your case the third terminal is plastic (non-conducting), so it doesn't act as a ground.

If the adapter is doubly isolated can be identified by looking at the markings. Below is the symbol you should be looking for (from [this page](https://www.electricalsafetyfirst.org.uk/guidance/advice-for-you/when-travelling/travel-adaptor-for-usa/) which contains some background information, although it focuses on travel adaptors):

[image: Double isoluted symbol]

The power adapter from [your other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144413/can-i-use-this-fast-charger-for-my-raspberry-pi-4) does have this symbol (and all adapters I can find in my house do have this symbol as well).

Answer (score 0):

No problem. 3.1A is the maximum current that it can deliver.

Answer (score -1):

When choosing power supply you need to check that the supplier (power supply) can deliver the current (power) the consumer (Raspberry Pi) needs.

And if the supplier (power supply) can provide more power than the consumer (Raspberry Pi) can consume then will it not be consumed.

So its a supply and demand scenario!